# How to pass data from an AuthorizeAttribute to the Controller using webapi 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a `custom AuthorizeAttribute` which verifies some `OAuth credentials of user`.

Once I got valid user I want to return response data to controller how can I achieve this in web api .net.

```
public class CustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = mydata.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (mydata.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            // return response data to controller
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I searched I got `in mvc` it `can be done like below`.

```
public class CustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   public string BlackListedUsers { get; set; }
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
   {
     filterContext.HttpContext.Items["test"] = "foo";
     return true;
   }
}
```

In controller -

```
_yourVariable = HttpContext.Items["test"];
```

How can I achieve this in `System.Web.Http` in `web api` because in webapi i do not have `method AuthorizeCore and input parameter AuthorizationContext`?

Comment: Through container and Dependency properties, for example.

Comment: in webapi i do not have method AuthorizeCore and input parameter AuthorizationContext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach can work but not recommended.

Inside your IsAuthorized function-

```
protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var response = mydata.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (mydata.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string someValue = "any value";
        actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("YourKeyName", someValue));
        return true;
    }
}
```

The `someValue` can be string, int or any custom object as you want.

In controller you retrieve like this-

```
object someObject;
Request.Properties.TryGetValue("YourKeyName", out someObject);
```

Comment: Is actionContext.Request.Properties per-user? I mean if two users set it at the same time to different values, then what happens?

Comment: Yes, Request properties are user specific

Answer (score 4):

In Web API 2.0 `HttpActionContext.Request.Properties` is equivalent to `AuthorizationContext .HttpContext.Items`. Consequently you can add an item to the properties and get it in your controller by `Request.Properties["keyName"]`.

```
public class CustomAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var response = mydata.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (mydata.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            actionContext.Request.Properties["keyName"] = keyValue;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have, for example, MyController with property MyProperty defined on that controller, then in authorize you might have something like:

```
(filterContext.Controller as MyController).MyProperty= "any value";
```

and within your controller you just normally access MyProperty

Answer (score 0):

I use Code Like this

```
 protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            BaseApiController Controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseApiController;
            baseApi.Property = 10;
            return Controller.IsAuthorize();
        }
```